# persistCombineReducers error : key is required in persitor config

Tags: react-native

I need help on the following code:

```
import { persistCombineReducers } from "redux-persist";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-community/async-storage";
import { ENV, STORAGE_PREFIX } from "RomulusTraining/App/Config";
import App from "RomulusTraining/App/Reducers/App";

const config = {
  key: STORAGE_PREFIX,
  debug: ENV === "development",
  storage: AsyncStorage,
};

const reducers = persistCombineReducers(config, {
  app: App,
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof reducers>;

export default reducers;
```

The error is on this line: const reducers = persistCombineReducers(config, {

Output: "key is required in persitor config"

Any help would be highly appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Found this https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/blob/master/docs/MigrationGuide-v5.md but the key is well defined in config ...

Comment: Found the error: STORAGE_PREFIX was not a String